# Two lines intersect at $O$ at an angle of $60^∘$

Tags: geometry

(Refer to diagram below) Two lines intersect at $O$ at an angle of $60^∘$. Two circles are drawn such that they are tangent to each other and the two lines. $A$ and $B$ are the centers of the smaller and larger, respectively. If the radius of the smaller circle is $15$, what is the length of $OB$?

[image]

Comment: Hint : Use similar triangles and find out the radius of the bigger circle. Then you can get to the value of $OB$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

I have just modified your figure with some constructions.

[image]

Use trigonometry on $\triangle ADO$,

$AD=15$. What's the angle $\angle DOA$? (Recall that $OA$ bisects $\angle DOC$)

$ \sin 30 ^\circ= \dfrac{AD}{AO}=\dfrac{15}{AO}=\dfrac{1}{2} \implies AO=30$

Note that $OEB \sim ODA$, you can solve the problem using these hints.:)

Answer (score 2):

Show that $OA, OB$ are the bisectors of $\angle O=60^\circ$

So, $OAB$ are co-linear

Now, apply trigonometry to find $OA =15\csc30^\circ=30 $

Now, $OB=30+15+R$ where $R$ is the radius of the larger circle

As the two triangles (one with OA & the smaller radius, the other with OB & the larger radius) are similar as the radii are perpendicular to the common tangents,
 $$\frac R{45+R}=\frac{15}{30}$$